# SnScrape not working. Says unable to find guest token

Tags: web-scraping, twitter

I've been using snscrape to scrape Tweets and it's been working fine for a month now. This morning I woke up and it's stopped. It says "unable to find guest token"

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to upgrade your Python version?

Snscrape will only work for 3.8. You need to use the developer version of Snscrape if you're working with a higher version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience whatsoever with the Twitter API, but last night a lot of third party Twitter apps stopped working. It sounds like the Twitter API is the culprit.

This may not be a software bug on your end.

Twitter API has now been closed to third party apps. This includes your application as well.

Comment: snscrape does not use the Twitter API